# Dynamical Ricatti equation and positive definite P?

Tags: matrices, dynamical-systems, positive-definite

So I'm working on a homework problem in a Mathematical Systems theory class, as this is homework I'd prefer some guidance or pointing in the right direction rather than a straight up solution.

The problem is as follows: Consider the dynamical Ricatti Equation
$\dot{P} = -A^TP - PA + PBB^TP - C^TC$

$P(t_1) = S$

$S \geq 0$

Where S is positive semi-definite. The first question is simple enough and it is to show that if (C,A) is observable then P(t) is positive definite $\forall t\in [0,t_1)$. However what I'm stuck on is that for question b) we're asked, if (C,A) is not observable, can P(t) still be positive definite $\forall t\in [0,t_1)$? I have no clue how to even begin answering the second question here.

Comment: I managed to somewhat answer the question for a specific case but still no general proof.